# Egg-shaped Feynman diagram

Tags: tikz-feynman

I was trying to answer [tikz-feynman: edge labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487519/tikz-feynman-edge-labels) when I encountered an odd problem:

Why is the first diagram slightly egg shaped? Without the lines left and right it is round. Please don't tell me this is because it had been easter this weekend :)

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram[horizontal=b to d] {
    a -- b,
    b -- [quarter right] 
    c -- [quarter right] 
    d -- [quarter right] 
    e -- [quarter right] 
    b,
    d -- f,
};

\feynmandiagram[horizontal=b to d] {
%   a -- b,
    b -- [quarter left] 
    c -- [quarter left] 
    d -- [quarter left] 
    e -- [quarter left] 
    b,
%   d -- f,
};

\end{document}
```

[image]

A list of package versions I use:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
tikz-feynman.sty    2016/02/05v1.1.0Feynman diagrams with TikZ
    tikz.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
     pgf.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgfrcs.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
  pgfsys.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2019/02/02 v3.1.1 (3.1.1)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 pgfopts.sty    2014/07/10 v2.1a LaTeX package options with pgfkeys
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: I get a very different output than you do, which is definitely not your fault. Rather, in general I find that the automatic graph drawing algorithms seem to make things harder than simplifying them.

Comment: I don't get neither a circle not an egg, but sort of squares with arc borders.

Comment: @marmot & UlrikeFischer Interesting! Maybe I use some old package version or something. I added a list just in case.

Comment: @valerie I could very well be that I am using older packages than you do. I have been watching this for a while now, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455001/121799), and my personal conclusion is that, unfortunately, this graph drawing stuff is in this context too fragile, so I personally do not use them (the more so since arXiv doesn't support `lualatex` anyway).

Comment: @marmot Ah, ok. I don't use it myself, so I better stay away from it

Comment: @marmot excuse me for intervening. The Easter eggs are also drawn to me that I have the MikTeX packages updated this morning (see the link to the original question).

Comment: Hi valerie, this is not necessarily what I want to imply but it is more to say that problems with the graph drawing library are not unheard of so it might be that you might be spending a lot of time and energy, and still won't get something that works for everyone. @Sebastiano I am not doubting that. Rather, this is the problem I have with this stuff: different machines yield very different results.